# Functional Equation from BMT 2020

Tags: functions, derivatives, functional-equations

Consider $f: R^+ \rightarrow R$ be differentiable and satisfy
$$f(y) - f(x) = \frac{x^x}{y^y} f\left(\frac{y^y}{x^x} \right)$$ for all x, y > 0. And $f^{'}(1) = 1$.
I need to find f(x). I tried differentiating both sides with respect to x but was not able to reach to the conclusion. Can I get a hint to approach this question? And what would be the line of thinking for such problems?

Comment: FYI, using an [Approach0 search](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24f(y)-f(x)%3D%5Cfrac%7Bx%5Ex%7D%7By%5Ey%7Df%5Cleft(%5Cfrac%7By%5Ey%7D%7Bx%5Ex%7D%5Cright)%24&p=1), there's the AoPS threads [Functional equations](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c7h1695950p10870745) and [Functional equation](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h1650913p10439390).

Comment: Looking at the point that the difference on the LHS causes a quotient, I was able to guess a logarithmic function. Then a quick observation told me that should be $f(x) = \ln(x^x)$ to account for the $x^x$ and $y^y$ in the RHS. The fact that $f: \color{blue}{\Bbb R^+} \to \Bbb R$ also provided a hint towards logarithms. That should be your line of thinking. For the proper solution, see the lined threads.